# RewriteRule - don't want to redirect my page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have problem with RewriteRule. I'm doing english version of website and RewriteRule doesn't seems to work:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/.* news.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^news newslist.php [NC,QSA]
```

It is weird because previouse version of this code works perfectly. Here it is:

```
RewriteRule ^aktualnosci/([0-9]+)/.* czytaj.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^aktualnosci aktualnosci.php [NC,QSA]
```

What could be wrong with first code? The first rule redirect me to newslist.php rule.

Comment: Well, the first rule rewrites to `/news....`, then the second rules rewrites that again immediately.

Comment: But second code I write is working OK. It is the same, just names are different.

Comment: No, it is _not_ the same. In the second example the first rule rewrites to `czytaj...` which will _not_ be matched by the second rule.

Comment: So it's just matter of file names?
EDIT: Yep, it depends on file names. Now it's working.

Comment: Strictly speaking yes, you implemented some from of collision in the first rule set. However I still think your patterns look funny, that is why I asked for examples below. The real thing you have to care about is not so much some name of finding a work around here, but the fact that you apparently you should try to gain a deeper understanding of what is going on, how this stuff works. Don't get me wrong, I am not unrespectful here! It is just that you last comment suggests that you think in wrong directions...

Comment: Maybe, you are right. Didn't know that filenames are also take in account in case of rewrite rule. I've never go deep enough to RewriteRule, just the things I need to do :) Thanks

Comment: Please, do yourself a favor and simply read through the official documentation of the rewriting module. That is no magic and the documentation is very wenn written. You see, the issue has _nothing_ to do with file names. Rewriting works purely on string base, here you simply had the issue that the rewriting to _the string_ "news.php" is again matched by the _string pattern_ "news"...

Answer (score 0):

The rules you posted are somewhat exotic... I dare say that *probably* you are looking for something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?news/([0-9]+)/?$ news.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/?news/?$ newslist.php [NC,L]
```

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank for explanation. But unfortunately your code doesn't work for me. I get 404 error on first rule. The first rule redirect me to the second page (news; newslist.php)

Comment: Please add two example request URLs to the question itself. Thanks.